# Solving a double integral with scipy dblquad

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, numerical-integration, symbolic-integration

I am trying to solve the double integral of this complicated function. The function contains 3 symbolic variables which are defined with `sympy.symbols`. My goal is to integrate the function with respect to only two of the variables. `sym.integrate` run for 2 hours with no results to show. I tried numerical integration with `scipy.integrate.dblquad`. But I am having troubles which I suspect is due to the third symbolic variable.

Is there a way to do this?

Problem summarized:

```
sym.symbols('x y z')
My_function(x,y,z)
```

Integrate `My_function` with respect to x and y (Both from 0 to inf i.e. definite integral).

```py
h, t, w, r, q = sym.symbols('h t  w r q')  # Define symbols

wn = 2.0
alpha = 1.76
beta = 1.59
a0 = 0.7
a1 = 0.282
a2 = 0.167
b0 = 0.07
b1 = 0.3449
b2 = -0.2073
psi = 0.05

F_H = 1.0 - sym.exp(-(h / alpha) ** beta)
mu_h = a0 + a1 * h ** a2
sig_h = b0 + b1 * sym.exp(b2 * h)
F_TIH = (1 / 2) * (1 + sym.erf((sym.log(t) - mu_h) / (sig_h * sym.sqrt(2))))

f_h = sym.diff(F_H, h)
f_tzIhs = sym.diff(F_TIH, t)
f_S = f_h * f_tzIhs

H = (1.0 - (w / wn) ** 2.0 + 1.0j * 2.0 * psi * w / wn) ** (-1.0)
S_eta_h_t = h ** 2.0 * t / (8.0 * pi ** 2.0) * (w * t / (2.0 * pi)) ** (-5.0) * sym.exp(-1.0 / pi * (w * t / (2.0 * pi)) ** (-4.0))

S_RIS_hu_tu = abs(H) ** 2.0 * S_eta_h_t

m0_s = sym.integrate((w ** 0 * S_RIS_hu_tu), (w, 0, np.inf))
m0_s.doit()

m2_s = sym.integrate((w ** 2 * S_RIS_hu_tu), (w, 0, np.inf))
m2_s.doit()

v_rIs = 1 / (2 * pi) * sym.sqrt(m2_s / m0_s) * sym.exp(-r ** 2 / (2 * m0_s))

fun = v_rIs * f_S

# The integral I am trying to solve is a function of h,t and r. 
integ_ht = sym.integrate(fun,(h,0,np.inf),(t,0,np.inf))
```

Comment: You would have to substitute a value for the third symbol to be able to use scipy. Otherwise if you want a symbolic result you need a symbolic integrator (i.e. sympy).

Comment: @OscarBenjamin , Thanks for the response! 
Thats the thing. I want a symbolic result. I tried with sympy, but it took almost two hours with no result to show. Is there a way to help sympy (guide it) so that the integration completes?

Comment: Then you can't use scipy. You will have to use sympy for this. There are potentially ways to help sympy with the integral depending on what it is. A basic mathematical fact is that not all functions can be integrated symbolically though.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin,Using sympy:  when I debug I see "Integral" of the function with the boundaries is created but not carried out. I used the .doit() method but did not help.

Comment: Apparently it's having trouble finding a `anti-derivative`.

Comment: @hpaulj, any suggestions?

Comment: No, especially without the function to look at.  There isn't to my knowledge any way of doing a partial numeric integration.  Numeric and symbolic packages are not a substitute for a good grounding in calculus.

Comment: @hpaulj , I have now posted the function I am trying to integrate. Please take a look at it if you can :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What is psi? Also use `sym.sqrt(2)` not `math.sqrt(2)` if you are working symbolically

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, sorry for the incomplete code..Its updated now
 psi = 0.05
And sym.sqrt it is :) , but no progress, taking forever with no results to show

Comment: I don't think that you will get an analytic solution for the earlier integrals let alone the double integral. You will need to do this numerically for different values of r.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, It seems like it. Thanks for your help :)